# At local minima/maxima, aren't functions constant for an infinitesimally small amount of time?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, tangent-line, slope

If you are looking at a graph of sine describing an object's motion at $\frac{\pi}{2}$, where the derivative is 0, doesn't this object have a constant position for an instant? I was thinking about how horizontal lines have zero slopes, which represent constant position in the physics example, and therefore have a derivative of zero. But these local maxima and minima have a derivative of zero at an instant, so it leads me to infer that they are constant along an infinitesimally small interval, or at a point. I wanted to describe the point in which it's constant as being multiples of  $\frac{\pi}{2}$. But my teacher said that only if the derivative is 0 at more than 1 point. Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: an "instant" is not really a mathematical term. you have points and intervals on the real line. a function is defined at a point. the derivative is also a function (where it can be defined).  the derivative may be used to provide a "good" linear approximation to the function on a "suitably small" interval containing a point, but this is only an approximation. so all you can say is that the function is "approximately constant" near a zero of its derivative.

Comment: @DavidHolden ah that makes sense. So we're essentially both right?